# Is it bad if bash is not up to date?

Tags: bash

Is it bad if bash is not up-to-date? Like on my Mac Mini, the bash version is 3.2.57(1)-release. Is it bad if I have that version of bash installed on my computer?

Comment: Recently I had to amend [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336773/7233423) due to that old version of bash on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessarily 'bad' but it will limit your functionality.  It is normal however.  I have a new 2017 macbook pro that also came with bash v 3.x and had to manually update it to v 4.  You can see some of the features that are unique to bash v4 here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4

However unless you are doing some advanced system administration/scripting I doubt you will run into any issues because of it so probably wont want to mess with upgrading it unless you are missing out on some needed functionality.

Comment: I followed this guide which uses homebrew: http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by *"not up-to-date"*? If it hasn't been patched since 2014, then yes, it is bad. [Quite bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) actually - only a step away from getting its own webpage. The security implications of the Shellshock bug are rather far reaching (apart from other things, it can affect any software that uses `popen()`) - you should update it as soon as possible (be it by getting the same version patched for the specific problems or a bleeding edge version, which is fixed as well).

Generally, running un-updated software is only acceptable (from the *security* point of view) on systems that process safe input all the time. Anything that an attacker can reach, should be regularly updated. *"Can reach"* meaning *"being able to influence"* here - regardless of whether it is via network the system is connected to or a legitimate user running some code copied from an internet forum.

Please note that just looking at the version number doesn't have to mean much - many UNIX like systems do actively patch the software they distribute. Too many times I've seen customers complaining about "old" package, because they didn't realize that security bugs were fixed while the rest of the code stayed untouched. Especially automated security scanners are good at producing this kind of false positives. The information you need is found in the package changelog.

Comment: By not up to date I mean that it is not up to date. I believe the current bash version is 4.x.xx(1)-release. But like I said, bash on my Mac mini is version 3.2.57(1)-release. I have recently found out that Apple does not update bash because of licensing stuff. Is it bad that the version of bash that is on my computer 3.2.57(1)-release?

Comment: @HunterT. I've updated the answer. Version number doesn't tell you much. You are going to need a changelog. However in this case I'm afraid the package hasn't been patched.